# Divider Item Decoration

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have this issue where the item in recycling view on top the line appears thicker below "Available Booking Request"

[run of the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfDHC.png)

This what I've used in the code.

```
DividerItemDecoration itemDecor = new DividerItemDecoration(ParentInfoSitter.this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecor);
```

What do I know the line should be equally shaped. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: This might be from the layout..Does it still exist if you remove the `ItemDecorator`?

Comment: @Zain yes, if I remove it, it does not exist. Shall I upload the layout code?